# Using maximum flow algorithm to check existence of a matrix

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, network-flow, network

Using the maximum flow algorithm, I have to determine if there exists a $3\times 3$ matrix $P$ (such that all elements are $\geq 0$). I'm given:

- The maximum values of the row sums
- The column sums
- The maximum value each element can take

I have a pretty good idea of how to build the network:

- Have three vertices $r_1, r_2, r_3$ represent the rows and have another three vertices $c_1, c_2, c_3$ represent the columns, with the capacity of each arc from $r_i$ to $c_j$ representing the maximum value of $i,j$-th entry in $P$
- Have a source $s$ with arcs between $s$ and each $r_i$ representing the maximum possible value for the sum of that row
- Have a sink $t$ with edges between each $c_j$ and $t$ representing the sum of that column

However, I'm at a loss on how to use the algorithm to check if such a $P$ can actually exist.

Comment: You're essentially done. Matrix $P$ exists iff there exists a solution in your network with flow equal to $(c_1,t) + (c_2,t) + (c_3,t)$.

Comment: So it basically just boils down to showing that the value of the maximum flow $\geq$ $(c_1,t) + (c_2,t) + (c_3,t)$?

Comment: Yes. Clearly the maximum flow in your graph is $\leq (c_1,t) + (c_2,t) + (c_3,t)$. Now if equality can be achieved, then what can you say about the matrix $P$ defined as $P_{ij} = (r_i,c_j)?$

Comment: Upon computing the maximum flow, $P$ will clearly satisfy all the requisite conditions, with each $p_{ij}$ element taking the value of the $(r_i,c_j)$ arc at termination?

Comment: That's right. You can check that each requisite (maximum row sum, column sums and maximum value of each element) is satisfied.